# Unable to run Oracle Forms application through FSAL mode

Tags: oracle, forms, weblogic, oracle12c, weblogic12c

Hello guys thats my problem.

Forms is on weblogic 12c and its version is also 12c.

I've downloaded FSAL jar from my host and configured .env files to permit FSAL to run them. After that, trying to execute my application got the following error

[error image 1/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2DoW.jpg)

[errir image 2/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZaO2.jpg)

If you need any information related to the enviroment or configuration files, I will edit the post and add it here.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there may be several possible issues.

1. You are using an unsupported Java version.  You appear to be using Forms 12.2.1.3. You can only use Java 8 with this version.  If you want to use Java 11, you must upgrade to 12.2.1.4
2. You have a demo JAR file configured (TimeoutPJC.jar) but it cannot be found.  Be sure this file is located in a virtually mapped directory.  IF you stored this file in \forms\java, you must restart WLS_FORMS after copying it there or it will not be found.
3. The old demo JARs were created with very old Java versions and likely need to have their Java code recompiled and new JAR files created.  Those JARs should also be properly signed.